# Same Apache poi (excel) code acting differently depending on system types (32bit, 64bit)

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have successfully generated an excel file using apache poi 3.10, the program only runs as expected on 32bit systems.

BUT when tried to run it on 64bit systems, most of the cells data are left out, they simply don't show up (but the same code will work just fine on 32bit systems). 
what can I do so that all the generated cell data can show even on 64bit systems?

```
HSSFWorkbook my_xls_workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(input_document);
HSSFSheet my_worksheet = my_xls_workbook.getSheetAt(0);

Cell cell = null;
cell = my_worksheet.getRow(0).getCell(10);
cell.setCellValue(nme.getText());                              
cell = my_worksheet.getRow(3).getCell(6);
cell.setCellValue(frm.getText);
cell = my_worksheet.getRow(4).getCell(3);
cell.setCellValue(empid);

//Closing InputStream
input_document.close();

FileOutputStream output_file =new FileOutputStream(new File("C:PayslipG.xls"));

//write data
my_xls_workbook.write(output_file);
//closing stream
output_file.close();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Java should be platform and architecture agnostic. Make sure you really have the same code and the same jars on both machines!

Comment: @Gagravarr Yes I do have the very same code and the very same jars on both machines but the problem persists.  Thanks a lot for your quick response and I am open to your new suggestions.

Comment: Can you use the code from [This Apache POI FAQ Entry](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006) to ensure there a no "bonus" extra POI jars hiding on the classpath of one machine?

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks to the link you just gave me, I found that Apache poi 3.10 was not the latest version released, so i decided to upgrade to Apache poi 3.13 (which the latest for now) and guess what, everything cell data is appearing now. Thank you so much for your time and your precious help. Peace!

Answer (score 0):

Promoting some comments to an answer - Java should be platform and architecture agnostic. Unless you're doing platform-specific code, eg AWT or Swing, there shouldn't be any differences between runtime platforms

The one thing the can differ between machines, however, is the classpath. Make sure you really have the same code and the same jars on both machines!

A sadly common problem is for runtimes, frameworks etc to silently bundle outdated copies of Apache POI without telling you. If you [make use of the code included in the Apache POI FAQ Entry](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006), you can check which POI jars you are really using at runtime.

As per the comments, those jars aren't the ones you think you are using. As per [this other POI FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N1019C), mixing POI jars between versions isn't supported. Remove the older POI jars as identified, so you only use the latest ones, and your code will behave correctly

Comment: Good idea to promote it to an answer so people in the situation I was in before your help can easily find the solution. Thank you @Gagravarr

Comment: @fmm Glad it fixed it for you! Please could you mark the answer as accepted (tick box by the voting), so others know it solves the issue?